# how to scrape a webpage after a login using python?

Tags: python, http, urllib, cookielib

I need to **scrape** facebook for my posts after i logged in, but i don't know how to "keep the connection alive".

I'm using urllib, and i know how to connect to a server, get the page, send the data, but i have no idea on how to handle the cookies to get to the page for which is required a login.
i found that i need cookielib to do the job, but cannot find a tutorial or something that explains how to get the job done.

Cn you help me in some way? or provide me with a link to a tutorial?

Comment: They probably have measures in place to detect this.

Comment: they have measures to detect if i connect to fb, get my last 3 posts and print them to my console? O_o how could they detect it?

Comment: Maybe not if you're just getting the last 3 posts then. But I agree with Jakob that the Facebook API is better - it's easier than scraping anyway

Comment: is it against the policy to write a chat too?

Comment: It's against policy to bypass the API in any way.

Comment: ok, i understand.. could you just point me to anything useful about logging in via a python script. i just wanted to do this "project" to learn how to do that, i'll be doing it with some other website if it's against fb policy..

Comment: You should make a habit of consulting terms and conditions before scraping any site.

Answer (score 3):

Please do not scrape your facebook page, its against the terms and conditions instead use the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) which allows you to register applications that can acquire posts

Comment: i wanted to get my last 3 posts, just because i wanted to.. but i wanted to try something else too, like writing on pages or writing messages via console.
i don't think facebook api allows you to do that or do they?

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you need to maintain a [CookieJar](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html#examples) in your application. This library is like a plugin for the Python HTTP client that lets you persist cookies (such as the login token that you are after) across your scraping session.

Note that you might need to [specify a valid user agent](http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/user_agent.html) for Facebook to accept your request.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the existing [Python for Facebook](http://www.pythonforfacebook.com/) library?  If you're just looking to hook into the API and post / retrieve status messages, I can't see it being that complicated.